# After deleted this table row, update another table specify columns in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

As you see below i have two table.

1.Posts Table (record the in and out of the table)

```
id  lecture_name    roomkey created_at  updated_at  user_id
1   Ee Vonne Ng     L02     2019-01-22  2019-02-03      1
2   Ee Vonne Ng     L03     2019-01-22  2019-01-23      1
```

2.key table (keynos)

```
id  roomkey status  created_at  updated_at
1   L01     0       2019-01-22  2019-02-04 
2   L02     1       2019-01-22  2019-01-22 
3   L03     1       2019-01-22  2019-01-22 
4   L04     0       2019-01-22  2019-02-04
```

I am having a problem as when i want to delete a record in posts,yes,i am successful, but i want it to update also the keyno status to 0, so that it act as this key is active. But i don't know what have i missed as i can delete but i can't update the keyno status. No error is show, but my status is not update. How anyone can help me or give me some advise TT

Below is my code.

> 1=Key in use 0=not in use

1.Post controller

```
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post =  Post::find($id);
    $post->delete();
    if($post->delete()){
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $key = Keyno::all();

        $postroomkey = $post->roomkey;
        Keyno::where('roomkey','=',$postroomkey)
        ->update(['status' => 0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try `Keyno::where('roomkey', $postroomkey)` instead of `Keyno::where('roomkey','=',$postroomkey)`

Comment: Still the status not update :(

Comment: Remove the first `$post->delete();`

Comment: "Trying to get property 'roomkey' of non-object"

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: OMG! It work! Thank you so so so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `$post->delete();` twice.

The first one will delete the post but second one doesn't actually do anything which means it returns false, because it can't find the post.

This means that your code in the `if` statement doesn't actually run. Change it to this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post =  Post::find($id);
    $postroomkey = $post->roomkey;
    if($post->delete()){
        $key = Keyno::all();

        Keyno::where('roomkey','=',$postroomkey)
        ->update(['status' => 0]);
    }
}
```

---

> "Trying to get property 'roomkey' of non-object"

This is probably due to `$post` not being an object anymore after you delete it, fetch `roomkey` before deleting it. Updated answer.